# Can someone suggest a code snippet to detect browser close event? Please don’t suggest ‘onbeforeunload’. I want to detect browser or tab close only

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Can someone suggest a code snippet to detect browser or tab close event? Please don’t suggest ‘onbeforeunload’. I want to detect browser or tab close only. Onbeforeunload event triggers when it tries to leave the site which doesn’t work in my case.

I tried onbeforeunload event. I was making ajax call to a post api to persist the data to db. The flow works fine but onbeforeunload does not apply in my case.

Comment: I don't think there's a distinct event for this.

Comment: Most applications that want to auto-save just use a timer. That's how Stack Exchange works when it auto-saves questions and answers.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.